VBA Code for auto hide some range in ws2, when some range in ws1 is changed
I want to have a vba code that auto hiding range row 1-10 in worksheet B if len cell B(1-10) is < 1 (null)
When value in cell D1:10 in worksheet A is changed
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)  
     Dim ws As Worksheet  
     Dim ws2 As Worksheet  
     Set ws = Sheets("A")  
     Set ws2 = Sheets("B")  
       
     If Target.Address = ws.Range("D1:D10") Then  
         ws2.Rows("1:10").Hidden = True  
           
        For a = 1 To 10 Step 1  
            If Len(ws2.Range("D" & a).Value) > 1 Then  
                Rows(a).Hidden = False  
             End If  
         Next a  
     End If  
End Sub


What is the issue?  There doesn't seem to be a question

I dont think your target address will be ws.Range("D1:D10") Intersect may help here.  For example application.Intersect(range("a5"),range("a1:a10")) is nothing is false, application.Intersect(range("a50"),range("a1:a10")) is nothing is true

What do you mean by "When value in cell D1:10 in worksheet A is changed"? When all cells from the respective range are changed? When a cell of that range is changed? When the respective range is selected? Or what? Then, you are talking about "if len cell B(1-10) is < 1" and in your code you use If Len(ws2.Range("D" & a).Value) \> 1 Then ...

When a cell of that range is changed*

My code doesn't work :" hmm can you explain more about intersect ? Im new to vba

What do you mean by "cell B(1-10) is < 1"? The row is empty? Cells in a specific column of these 10 rows are empty (in D:D)? Or what?

As commenters point out, you likely want to use the Intersect function, which returns a range that includes cells that exist in both the Target and the Range you're interested in. If that is not empty, then at least one of the cells in the Range has changed. So, try this Worksheet Change event (note, not Selection Change):
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("A")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("B")
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("D1:D10")) Is Nothing Then
        ws2.Rows("1:10").Hidden = True
        For a = 1 To 10
            If Len(ws2.Range("D" & a).Value) > 1 Then
                ws2.Rows(a).Hidden = False
            End If
        Next a
    End If
End Sub

